# Select/Export records based on top 10 descriptive values by count

Tags: arcgis-pro

Let's say I want to select and then export records/features based on top 10 descriptive values by count.

Now I know I can find the top 10 descriptive (`text data type`) values and determine their count using the `Frequency` tool. I can then use the `Select by Attributes` tool to enter `10` `Where and OR` clauses to select those top 10 descriptive values and then export the selected records as a new feature class.

Is there a better way to do this in ArcGIS Pro 3.1?

Comment: Sounds like a task suited to [data engineering](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.0/help/analysis/geoprocessing/data-engineering/quick-tour-of-data-engineering.htm)?

Comment: Try IN in your query, e.g. Name in ('A', 'F'...'W')

Comment: A better way would be to use ArcPy or ModelBuilder.

Comment: @PolyGeo, can you please suggest a ModelBuilder approach in your answer?

Comment: I have not provided an answer, only a comment because I'm not planning to write an answer.  A test model for that would start with the Frequency tool, probably followed by Table Select to get the top 10 values into a table ready to iterate the Select tool on.